# Как читать любой байт в сжатом файле за константное время?

Tags: python, архивация, сжатие

Ищу способ читать произвольный байт в сжатом файле за константное время. Использую Python. Пробовал использовать zipfile и функцию seek, однако чем дальше от начала читаемый байт, тем медленнее он считывается. Какая из библиотек предоставляет доступ ко всем байтам файла за одинаковое время?

Comment: Самый простой способ - это распаковать этот файл. Желательно в память. И уже тогда время чтения любого байта будет одинаковым.

Comment: Почти все существующие форматы сжатия данных (zip и т.д.) не совместимы с требованием быстрого излечения байта в середине потока.  Нужные Вам алгоритмы сжатия существуют, но в основном в виде академических статей.  Короче, Вам придётся писать такой алгоритм самому.

Comment: @newman Именно так я сейчас и делаю. 2,5TB размер файлов, отсортированы для бинарного поиска. При сжатии будет 400GB, что куда удобнее. Сейчас я делю файлы на куски по 100 000 строк, тогда можно извлекать за 0.5 секунды. Но это всё равно не сравнится со скоростью чтения из файла без архива, в этом случае 0.01 секунды.

Comment: @ESkri
Я смог нагуглить про метод архивации LZO, для него существуют удобные библиотеки?

Comment: Ну, поделите на более мелкие куски. Это во-первых. Во-вторых пакуйте каждый кусок чем-то быстрым, да, из семейства LZ, например. Только не LZW к примеру и без вероятностного кодирования в конце, просто ссылки на повторы фрагментов чтобы были. Всё остальное довольно сильно замедляет. Вам нужно очень быстрое раскодирование.

Comment: Поместите файлы в распакованном виде на том/устройство/диск на котором включено сжатие средствами операционной системы. Во-первых, это может сработать само по себе. Во-вторых, это даст вам оценки сколько места займут файлы и сколько времени нужно будет чтобы их считывать если вы примените аналогичный алгоритм сжатия руками.

Comment: Какой формат записи в файлах? Какие данные?

Comment: @ESkri, сжатый том - пример сжатых данных с произвольным доступом. И это реальная технология, работающая везде где есть Windows. Про Linux не скажу - не знаю.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Кстати, отличная мысль. Зачем изобретать велосипед, если есть готовое удобное, прозрачное решение.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - `сжатый том - пример сжатых данных с произвольным доступом.` - Да, но там единицей доступа является дисковый кластер (несколько килобайт),  за счёт такого разделения данных коэффициент сжатия довольно скромный, меньше чем у zip на больших файлах.

Comment: @Mixam - LZO Вам не подходит